# Laravel Route Model Binding to Route::controller()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've got the following routes:

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    'admin' => 'AdminController',
    'site' => 'SiteController'
]);
```

And then I've got the following method in the `SiteController`:

```
/**
 * Get site details and pass to view
 *
 * @param Site $site
 * @return mixed
 * @internal param $site_id
 */
public function getDetails( Site $site )
{
    return $site;
}
```

When I go to the URL `site.com/site/details/13` it doesn't return the site object.

I've added `$router->model( 'one', 'App\Site' );` into the `RouteServiceProvider` and it works, but what if later down the road I want to add another controller like this but use it for `jobs`, and use the `getDetails` method again and pass through the `App\Job` object? It will automatically send the `App\Site` model instead.

So is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

My limited knowledge of Laravel tells me you can't have a model/object as parameter in your route controller functions, and that you don't need something like `$router->model( 'one', 'App\Site' );` to do this.

I'm assuming you'd want to do something like this:

As for your routes:

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    'admin' => 'AdminController',
    'site' => 'SiteController',
    'jobs' => 'JobController',
]);
```

In your `SiteController`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App/Site; //replace with namespace of model    

public function getDetails($id)
{
    //code for fetching the site object, depends on how your structure is, 
    //like $site = App\Site::find($id); etc

    return $site;
}
```

Similarly, your `JobController` will be something like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App/Job; //replace with namespace of model    

public function getDetails($id)
{
    //code for fetching the job object, depends on how your structure is, 
    //like $job = App\Job::find($id); etc

    return $job;
}
```

Look here: [Laravel Docs - Implicit Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#implicit-controllers)

Comment: I'm trying to prevent the `$id` parameter part of it though. That's the whole point of route model binding. I do appreciate your answer though.